# AnimationDrawable cannot be applied to android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable[]

Tags: android, android-animation, drawable, android-graphics

I was trying to implement an animation which would make the background of a linearlayout to oscilate between two colors.

I used this code to test a transition, which worked:

```
ColorDrawable[] color = {new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE), new ColorDrawable(Color.RED)};
TransitionDrawable trans = new TransitionDrawable(color);
holder.mItem_RowHolder.setBackground(trans);
trans.startTransition(3000);
```

holder.mItem_Rowholder contains the "getElementById" result of the Linearlayout I am speaking about.

Since the transition only allows a transition, and not a loop, I read I needed to use the AnimationDrawable function instead, from the same library (android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable)

I tested the following code:

```
ColorDrawable[] color = {new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE), new ColorDrawable(Color.RED)};
AnimationDrawable trans = new AnimationDrawable(color);
holder.mItem_RowHolder.setBackground(trans);
```

but I get an error on the line `AnimationDrawable trans = new AnimationDrawable(color);` which states `AnimationDrawable cannot be applied to android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable[]`

any idea of why?
In theory, the constructors of both "TransitionDrawable" and "AnimationDrawable" require an "android.graphics.drawable"...

Thanks!